# My scope doesn't work on a certain controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

my ruby version is 1.9.3 and my rails version is 3.2.2 and I'm using windows 7.

I created a controller and a model with the name of timeline to register the creation of another table called "Issues", here are my prompt commands

```
rails g controller timeline index
rails g model timeline content timelineable_type timelineable_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Everything was working okay, but then I putted a pt.yml as locale, and tried to put a scope for the adress, like this, on my routes.rb:

```
  scope "/:locale" do

    get "/timeline/index"

    resources :projects

    resources :issues
  end
```

But when I try to reach the page "localhost:3000/en/timeline/index", I get the folowing error:

```
Routing Error

wrong constant name :locale
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Could anyone help me ?

This is the timeline/index.html.erb:

```
<h1>Timeline</h1>

<div class="content2">
    <div id="fundo">
    <div class="row table-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 oi" align="left">Message</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 oi" align="left">Issue </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 oi" align="left">Created at</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <% @timelines.each do |timeline| %>
    <div class = "row" id="baixo">
        <div class="col-md-4"><%=timeline.content %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><%=link_to timeline.timelineable.title, issue_path(id: timeline.timelineable_id) %></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><%=time_ago_in_words timeline.created_at %></div>
    </div>
    <%-end%>
</div>
```

This is the timeline controler:

```
class TimelineController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @timelines = Timeline.all
  end
end
```

This is the timeline model:

```
class Timeline < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :timelineable, polymorphic: true
end
```

On my Issue model:

```
  after_create :add_to_timeline
  before_save :strip_spaces_from_tags

  private

  def add_to_timeline
    Timeline.create!({content: "An issue was created!", timelineable_id: id, timelineable_type: self.class.to_s})
  end

  def strip_spaces_from_tags
    self.tags.gsub! ", ", ","

  end
```

This is the application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

   before_filter :set_locale

   def set_locale
     I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
   end
end
```

My rake routes:

```
timeline_index GET    /:locale/timeline/index(.:format)    :locale/timeline#index
      projects GET    /:locale/projects(.:format)          projects#index
               POST   /:locale/projects(.:format)          projects#create
   new_project GET    /:locale/projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
  edit_project GET    /:locale/projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
       project GET    /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
               PUT    /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
               DELETE /:locale/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
        issues GET    /:locale/issues(.:format)            issues#index
               POST   /:locale/issues(.:format)            issues#create
     new_issue GET    /:locale/issues/new(.:format)        issues#new
    edit_issue GET    /:locale/issues/:id/edit(.:format)   issues#edit
         issue GET    /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#show
               PUT    /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#update
               DELETE /:locale/issues/:id(.:format)        issues#destroy
```

Anyone knows how can I fix this ?

Comment: Is it possible to scope to a dynamic module like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timeline_index` is routing to `:locale/timeline#index`, when actually it should route to `timeline#index`, shouldn't it?

Try to specify the controller and action in your, e.g.

```
get "timeline/index", to: "timeline#index"
```

Or you could try to achieve the same with `resources`, but be aware to rename your controller to its plural form, i.e. `TimelinesController`.

```
resources :timelines, only: [:index]
```

Should you feel uncomfortable with this approach because you may have only one timeline, you could try

```
resource :timeline, only: [:show]
```